# TeamCity and Office365 / Windows Active Directory integration

Tags: teamcity, office365, azure-active-directory

We have all our corporate users in Office365 and in Azure Portal we can see the users in the active directory.

I'd like to configure TeamCity to use this as a user store so all our users comes from there.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on this integration at the moment. Will announce it via @lodkin twitter account.
update: plugin home page https://github.com/ekoshkin/teamcity-azure-active-directory

Comment: I'll be waiting for you over there then. Looking forward to see how you solved it. Any idea of the time you need to complete the task?

Comment: You're a star man! I'll give that a shot asap! Please edit the answer to add the link.